# update ui on alert dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have an `Activity` which has Submit `Button`. On click of Submit, an `AlertDialog` is displayed, which has a Save `Button`. Now on click of an item in List the `Button` is displayed. I select some value and click save on alertdialog. Now on save I need to update item String in the List. However it doesn't work.

on save in `AlertDialog` I have called

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(EditPropertyActivity.this,
                    SetProperties.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

How do I make sure that I do not call the activity again and update the ui.

Comment: Please be more clear on what your are doing.Put code or logs here.Its not clear from your questions

Comment: I hope i got your problem right: why are you trying to start your Activity all over again (via an startActivity Intent)? just dismiss your Dialog and update your list, if this is all you want to do.

Comment: please be more clear in posting your Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have called finish() in save function you need to call the activity again.

Instead of that before dismissing edit your list and the dismiss your dialog.
in function on save button click

1. update your ArrayList
2. listviewObject.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Thanks a ton! I put the below code in the in `onClick()` of save '`Button` on the `AlertDialog` and it works! :)  `SetProperties.propsList = getProperties();
PropertyAdapter adapter = (PropertyAdapter) SetProperties.listview.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
finish();`